# MySQL WorkBench não está importando o banco, o que fazer?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql

Não estou conseguindo importar o banco que acabei de salvar para o Workbench. Aparece a mensagem de finalizado, porém não transfere o banco, já olhei tutoriais mas sem resultados, já atualizei os schemas e etc.

```
Restoring C:\Users\User1\Documents\dumps\Dump20210525.sql
Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\USE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpex660atv.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\dumps\\segundobanco.sql"
10:46:13 Import of C:\Users\User 1\Documents\dumps\segundobanco.sql has finished
```

Quando não é a mensagem acima, é a seguinte:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected
```